# Android SDK Check Not Working

Tags: android, sdk, lint

I am trying to change the transition from default to sliding in. I would like to keep my minSdkVersion to be 3 however overridePendingTransition wasn't added until API level 5 (Android 2.0).

I tried creating an integer to represent the SDK version and then only override the transition when in Android 1.6 or less via a simple if statement.

```
int sdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
if(sdkVersion>=5)
   overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Eclipse gives me a LINT warning stating "Call requires API level 5 (current min is 3): android.app.Activity#overridePendingTransition"

If I suppress this error and run it anyway it crashes on Android 1.6 or lower.

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it? Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest file you have this ...

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="latest version" />
```

Change the min sdk version to 5 like show below

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="latest version" />
```

Comment: I would like to keep my minSdkVersion at 3 so that I may target more devices. Is there any way to implement certain features for one SdkVersion? I don't want to exclude devices over a simple transition change so I would like to only override the transition in devices at and above API level 5.